# Horizontal Image Scrolling

Tags: css

Here is a link to a website that has the exact scroll effect I am trying to recreate: http://www.kellerhouse.com/

Does anyone have an idea how this was created?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The website you mention have used Flash to achieve this effect - but you can easily re-create this using JavaScript and there are already lots of scripts written that do this.

http://blog.dreamcss.com/wp-content/uploads/example/

http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/01.html